# Call class extends Fragment method from a class extends Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How do I call a class which extends a fragment from a class which extends a fragment?I have tried looking through various tutorials and Stack Overflow questions but when I try to implement the `getParentFragment()` I get an error `returns null`

My MySetting.class:

```
public class MySettings extends Fragment {

    public static MySettings s_HomeActivity;
    s_HomeActivity=this;

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                alert.setTitle("Text");
                alert.setMessage("Name");

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
                alert.setView(input);
                alert.setPositiveButton("Add",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                String value = input.getText().toString();
                                MyJournalEvents m =(MyJournalEvents)s_HomeActivity.getParentFragment();
                                m.AddNewDisp(value);

                            }
                        });
                alert.setNegativeButton("Отмена",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                // Canceled.
                            }
                        });
                alert.show();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) {
                int t = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

My MyJournalEvents.class:

```
public class MyJournalEvents extends Fragment {

public void AddNewDisp(String name) {
    dataAdapterDisp.add(name);
    dataAdapterDisp.sort(null);
    dataAdapterDisp.notifyDataSetChanged();
    spComboDisp.setSelection(dataAdapterDisp.getPosition(name));
    saveConection(xxx, "xxx", "xxx", "xxx",
            "xxx", "xxx");
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? From what I understand you want a fragment that have another fragment inside and you want them both communicating?

Comment: you can keep the reference of MyJournalEvent in activity and call it by getActivity().obj.AddNewDisp()

Comment: That's two separate files. It'not a fragment in fragment. I want to call one fragment method from the other

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Android, Fragments are not designed to work like that (calling methods from each other).

There are multiple ways to implement the communication between fragments and you can read more about how Android Fragments are designed to work [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). You can also find a sample there with example regarding this topic.